# HTML jumps to top of page when other field become visible

Tags: asp.net

I have some cs in my page that when a bullet is selected a text box displays to give information about why it was selected.  The problem I have is that when the bullet is selected and the text box appears, the page always jumps to the top and the user has to scroll back down.

This also causes my fileupload fields to have their text disappear if they start uploading and then change a bullet on the rest of the page.

Anyone know of a way to stop it from jumping and protect the fileupload fields from having their data reset?

```
<p>
<asp:Label ID="lblstoretooling" runat="server" Text="If no, why?"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtstoretooling" runat="server" height="50px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<br>
<p>Did you delete program(s) from the "To Machine" folder?
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="isdeletedprogram" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="isdeletedprogram_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="position: relative;">
<asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</p>
```

CS

```
if (isdeletedprogram.SelectedValue == "No")
    {
        txtdeletedprogram.Visible = true;
        lbldeletedprogram.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: You mean CSS? Please proof read.

Comment: can you share only the client source code, not cs code.. I guess that it has anchor element generated somewhere..

Comment: You mean the webconfig?  Sorry I am not very fluent with HTML.  I know enough to get by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by an automated postback:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="isdeletedprogram" runat="server" 
                     AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="isdeletedprogram_SelectedIndexChanged"
                     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="position: relative;">
```

When you click a radiobutton a full PostBack occurs to your page. In other words: your page gets reloaded and all your progress is lost. You have to manually save the current state of the objects you want to persist.

So what you would need to do is create a method that saves all your elements states in either Session, ViewState or Cache and one to load all your elements from it on page load.

```
//call this one in your isdeletedprogram_SelectedIndexChanged 
protected void SavePageState()
{
    Session["IsDeletedState"] = isdeletedprogram.SelectedIndex;
    /*...*/
}

//call this on in the else clause - when a postback occurs
protected void LoadPageState()
{
    isdeletedprogram_SelectedIndexChanged = Session["IsDeletedState"];
    /*add any server side controls state you want to save here*/
}
```

Your Page.Load would then look something like this

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    if(!Page.IsPostback)
    {
        //do anything you would normally do
    }
    else
    {
        //this will get executed on a Postback. Load data here
        LoadPageState()
    }
}
```

It is up to you to decide which kind of persistent memory you chose here. Session, Cache, ViewState ...

Comment: So I would nee dot do this for every section of the page that has the radiobutton that would refresh the page?